# Microsoft Surface Pro 4 running without a battery

Tags: battery, microsoft-surface-pro-4

Hi i have a use case where we would like to use the Microsoft Surface pro 4 without a battery, eg. running it only from its power supply. It is possible to remove the battery as per this ifixit guide: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Microsoft+Surface+Pro+4+Battery+Replacement/60358#

The question however is will it run without a battery?

Comment: What’s wrong with keeping the battery inside?

Comment: For this particular application we cant have batteries around in the enviroment.

Comment: I see. In that case, I’d say the Surface Pro 4 is simply not a suitable device. You most likely want a touchscreen. Those are available separately, also in industry-“hardened” versions. Try looking into these.

Comment: Agreed, simply using a rugget windows 10 tablet with replacable batteries would indeed be much easier. But not add to the estetics like the Surface does. So from a technical point of view i would still be interested if anyone has experience with running the surface 4 without the battery inside it.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to remove my surface pro 4 battery. It was malfunctioning and also had produced some gas inside the battery cover so the lcd was about to break. Since it was out of gaurantee I did the removal my self.
The result was a big no to your question.
It wont turn on without the battery in the circuit.

I removed battery from a surface pro 4 , it works fine , if one clicks on battery settings it simply reports @no battery present “ & a little cross over battery icon , it works as normal plugged in

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a separate answer: You CAN run the Surface without a battery. You have to make sure that the contacts of the mainboard that connected to the old battery don't short-circuit by touching the chassis of the Surface. I put a piece of paper between chassis and mainboard and my Surface Pro 4 turned on again. See also this reddit thread where a user reports the same thing: https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/ix3ov9/can_the_surface_pro_4_run_without_a_battery_pack/g68z5lv
Note: I would not recommend paper as a long term solution due to the risk of fire.

Answer (score 2):

Full credit goes to @Christian for the comment to @Hossein's answer, I have just verified that the Surface Pro 4 can indeed run without a battery if the contacts that should connect it to the motherboard are insulated from the aluminum chassis. There's even an adhesive patch that can be reused for this purpose.